# Connecting to SQL Server with a QT application in windows

Tags: qt, qt4, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2008R2 with my qt application in windows but I am getting errors. Here's what I am doing:

```
#include "ui_test1.h";
#include "QtSql/QtSql";

void Test1::on_btnsnd_clicked()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("ODBC");

    db.setHostName("ITPL_PC1");
    db.setDatabaseName("Test");
    db.setUserName("sa");
    db.setPassword("insforia");
    db.open();
    QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel;

    QString query = "insert into qttable(PID) values('ARUP')";
    model->setQuery(query, db);

    db.close();
}
```

i am getting this error 27 times :

```
 test1.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)        public: __thiscall QSqlDatabase::~QSqlDatabase(void)" (__imp_??1QSqlDatabase@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall Test1::on_btnsnd_clicked(void)" (?on_btnsnd_clicked@Test1@@AAEXXZ)
```

I don't know how to do this (I found this in google.)

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: What errors do you get? What do `QSqlDatabase::lastError()` and `QSqlQueryModel::lastError()` say?

Comment: i am getting this error when i am running the app `test1.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QSqlDatabase::~QSqlDatabase(void)" (__imp_??1QSqlDatabase@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall Test1::on_btnsnd_clicked(void)" (?on_btnsnd_clicked@Test1@@AAEXXZ)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MSVC, you should add `%QTDIR%/lib/QtSql4.lib` to Release configuration of your project and `%QTDIR%/lib/QtSqld4.lib` to Debug one. You should change `4` in file names to `500`, if you use Qt 5.0. So, file names would be `%QTDIR%/lib/QtSql500.lib` and `%QTDIR%/lib/QtSqld500.lib`

[image: Project Properties]

---

If you use QtCreator you should add the next line into your `.pro` file

```
QT += sql
```

**Upd:** added description for QtCreator's `.pro` file

Comment: how to find this window... sorry i am very new to qt

Comment: in my `.pro` file i have added like this : `LIBS += "C:\Qt\4.8.4\lib\QtSql4.lib";

LIBS += "C:\Qt\4.8.4\lib\QtSqld4.lib";` now i am getting an error `:-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Qt\4.8.4\lib\QtSql4.lib;'`

Comment: You can simple add this line: `QT += sql` to `.pro` file. And remove that `LIB` lines. P.S. Sorry, but you didn't tell aboud IDE you used. I thought that it's MSVC. Now I see, that it's QtCreator.... I'll edit answer

Comment: ok i solved that, sorry for not telling that.. and thanks for the solution .. but i am facing another problem regarding this can just take a look at that ... here's the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556193/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-2008-with-qt)